# How to implement LDAP authentication in grails with spring-security-core-ldap plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap, grails-plugin

I am new to grails and trying to implement LDAP authentication. I was reading the official document where it says: 
"There are three options for mapping LDAP attributes to UserDetails data (as specified by the grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.mapper.userDetailsClass config attribute) and hopefully one of those will be sufficient for your needs."
It makes it clear to use custom one but i couldn't find any information and usage about these three options. What are they and how can i use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're described in section 3 on configuration: "use 'person' to create a Person, 'inetOrgPerson' to create an InetOrgPerson, or null to create an LdapUserDetailsImpl".